# Enum for two class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I have two class `Customer` and `Passenger` (who in flight) with same attribute gender. So in the Customer class I declare enum gender

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum GENDER: {MALE: 1, FEMALE: 2}
end
```

And this enum is also used by Passenger class.

What is the best practice in this case ?
Should I split this enum to another class (for example: GenderHelper) ?

If yes, how can I declare enum in the helper class ? Inherit from ActiveRecord::Base like a model ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a concern and include it in both `Customer` and `Passenger`.

**app/models/concerns/gender.rb**

```
module Gender
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    enum GENDER: {MALE: 1, FEMALE: 2}
  end
end
```

**app/models/customer.rb**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Gender
end
```

Comment: So you mean when I want to use Gender enum, I have to call Customer.GENDERs[:MALE], for example, and Passenger.GENDERs[:MALE]. Is this good practice for  using common enum ?

Comment: Conclusion, the enum MUST belongs to an ActiveRecord class type, right ?